# How to open a sharded MongoDB (without replica set) environment on my dev machine?

Tags: mongodb

I have only found this tutorial [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/) which seems to be most recent, other tutorials it seems are outdated and don't work anymore.

I want to create a sharded, non-replicated cluster on my dev machine and I couldn't find how to do it in Mongo 3.4

Comment: What O/S are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have one member replica set as a minimum. You will also need config server to keep track of shards.

Reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-components/#development-configuration

> For testing and development, you can deploy a sharded cluster with a
>   minimum number of components. These non-production clusters have the
>   following components:
>
> A replica set config server with one member. At least one shard as a
>   single-member replica set. One mongos instance.

**WARNING**:
Use the test cluster architecture for testing and development only.

Answer (score 0):

One node replica sets are fine, but you don't need even that. Normal nodes are fine. Check [here](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/02/setting-up-sharded-mongodb-cluster-in-localhost.html) simple steps to create sharded cluster.